# Informix onunload/onload between different arch

Tags: backup, restore, informix

I have some necro-project using Informix Dynamic Server Version 7.31.UD1.
I need to backup-restore database between servers. The thing is, the `onload` just silently exits and doesn't create a database, giving no errors. I've successfully used this method on the same server to perform a backup/restore routine, so I'm almost sure I'm doing it right:

```
<console A>
[root@s10-zone informix]# rm -rf /tmp/.dbld                                 
[root@s10-zone informix]# mkfifo /tmp/.dbld                                 
[root@s10-zone informix]# cat /opt/oracle/exchange/perms32_unl > /tmp/.dbld

<console B>
[informix@s10-zone ~]$ onload -t /tmp/.dbld -b 100 -d default rist
Please mount tape and press Return to continue ...
<I press Enter, 2-5 seconds pass, nothing happens>
```

The only explanation so far is that the `onunload` backup was don on a i386 arch, and I'm doing `onload` import on an amd64 server, - am I right assuming it fails because of this ? The official documentation says *"If the page sizes are different, `onload` fails. If the alignment or numeric data types on the two computers are different (for example, with the most significant byte as last instead of first, or different float-type representations), the contents of the data page could be misinterpreted."*, but the page size of identical (4K), not so sure about float representation though.

Comment: As you're probably aware, IDS version 7.31 has been out of support for some years now.  That isn't going to make anything any easier.  Presumably, that's what you're referring to when you mention "necro-project".  Mixing and matching onload or onunload images is fraught.  Is the new machine using the same version of Informix — both using 7.31.UD1 and not 7.31.FD1 on the new machine?  If both are using UD1, then I'd expect it to work; if the new machine is using FD1, I'd be much less confident.

Comment: Well, I'm using even the same binary tree as on the source server (just copied it from it).